# How can I run npm script on Windows if command is in an external file

Tags: windows, cmd, npm

I have the following `package.json` file:

```
{
  "name": "bytemonster",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "simple npm build scss",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "build-css": "node-sass --include-path scss scss/main.scss public/css/main.css",
    "build-css2": ".\bin\builditcss"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "node-sass": "^3.6.0"
  }
}
```

I am using Windows. When I run `npm run build-css`, everything runs file. However, running `npm run build-css2` throws an error.

In the same directory as my `package.json` file, I created a `bin` folder and a `builditcss` file within that `bin` folder. My `builditcss` file contains the same command as the `build-css` script command in my package.json:

`node-sass --include-path scss scss/main.scss public/css/main.css`

How can I run `npm run build-css2` successfully on Windows if my npm command is located outside of my `package.json` file?

I know Windows uses `cmd` instead of `bash` and I would like to know how. I know there are better ways to handle this, but I'm looking for a `cmd` only solution.

Answer (score 0):

Install GIT and then use GIT-Bash.

Comment: I was looking for an answer along the lines of creating a `.cmd` or `.bat` file, but now realize that this problem has nothing to do with GIT-Bash. Its a node npm problem I was having due to my lack of understanding.

Answer (score 0):

I now understand why I couldn't run `npm run build-css2`. Its because I was trying to execute something that should have been on the command line interface instead of as a script. I should have created a .js file with code along the lines of

```
var sass = require('node-sass');
sass.render({
  file: scss/main.scss,
  [, options..]
}, function(err, result) { /*...*/ });
```

Then I can use node to run that script. I could even create a .bat, .cmd, or .sh file that contains "node [script_name]" and run that on the command prompt or terminal.